# Address Book: Is there any way to move the fields up/down?

Tags: mac, contacts

Is there any way to move the fields within Address Book up or down? I like to have order on my address book and it looks really bad when the phone number fields are all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot change the order they appear in, you can only change what fields are shown in the Template Section of the Preferences.